# Postgres function syntax near at IF

Tags: postgresql, function

I am writing a Postgres function as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.get_managing_owner(p_imo integer, p_charter_id integer)
RETURNS TABLE(managing_owner character varying) 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY
IF p_charter_id = 0
THEN
    SELECT managing_owner
    from dbo.vessel
    where imo=p_imo
    union
    SELECT managing_owner
    from dbo.charter c
    where imo=p_imo;
ELSE 
    SELECT managing_owner
    from dbo.vessel v
    inner join dbo.charter c2
    on v.imo =c2.imo
    where c2.id =p_charter_id
    union
    SELECT managing_owner
    from dbo.charter c
    where id=p_charter_id;
END IF;
end;
$function$
;
```

I am getting syntax error near at IF, I am not able to find any problem here. Can someone please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be like

```
BEGIN
 
IF p_charter_id = 0
THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT managing_owner
    from dbo.vessel
    where imo=p_imo
    union
    SELECT managing_owner
    from dbo.charter c
    where imo=p_imo;
ELSE 
    RETURN QUERY SELECT managing_owner
    from dbo.vessel v
    inner join dbo.charter c2
    on v.imo =c2.imo
    where c2.id =p_charter_id
    union
    SELECT managing_owner
    from dbo.charter c
    where id=p_charter_id;
END IF;
```